# iOS - Need to understand what devices work with CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I'm new to iOS CoreBluetooth - I setup a central manager correctly (saw a few tutorials and watched the WWDC).  However, my delegate "didDiscoverPeripherals" is not yielding me any results from my two bluetooth headsets - one is about 6 years old and the other I just bought is version 3.0.

I went to the grocery store and ran my app again - there it found three devices. So I need to better understand are there only certain devices (based on their version,etc) that will respond to iOS CoreBluetooth? If so, how can I identify these kinds of devices that will only work with this framework?  What alternatives are there to discover the non-supported devices?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CoreBluetooth is used only to connect to device that use bluetooth low energy, its quiet a bit different than classic bluetooth. I don't know much about headsets but I would guess most of them use standard bluetooth as Bluetooth low energy is meant for small data transmission.

As far as connecting to devices that aren't bluetooth low energy, there isn't really an easy way as apple restricts most classic bluetooth connects to devices made in their Made For iPhone program.

Comment: For information purpose Bluetooth LowEnergy or LE use Bluetooth 4.0 specifications but a device branded as Bluetooth 4.0 can use classical implementation instead of the LE one.